# Download Repository

Tags: maven, download, repository, nexus

I am trying to download whole repository from nexus.

I tried to curl and wget -OL -m -r options URL, nothing worked.

> error: connection timed out

Comment: Consider including the exact curl command you used and the exact results. Also consider reporting on any basic troubleshooting you may have done: internet connection check, credential check, etc.

Comment: What are you trying? If you are trying to download MavenCentral: This is impossible due to size. If you are trying to download a company repository: What for? Why not just use it with Maven?

Comment: What version of NXRM is this for?